# Centering vertical text in table moves it left instead of the centering it

Tags: tables, rotating

When I try to align the text to be centered on this image it instead moves left, any suggestions would be appreciated! A snippet is included below

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc|cc|cc}
   & 
   & Ground Truth & Spatial Mask & Output & Random Mask & Output\\

 \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Mask Coverage}} & 
  {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{70\%}} % this is aligning on the side of the image&
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/gt/00135.png} &   
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/ganr/00130.png} &
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/ganr/00130.png} &
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/ganr/00130.png} &
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/ganr/00130.png}\\
  
  & {\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{60\%}} &
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/gt/00135.png} &   
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/ganr/00130.png} &
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/ganr/00130.png} &
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/ganr/00130.png} &
  \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/ganr/00130.png}\\
```

The end product is included here for reference.
[image: End product when compiled]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
 \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{70\%}} % this is aligning on the side of the image
 \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/gt/00135.png}
```

so the centre of the 70% is aligned with the reference point of the image (which is its bottom edge)

You could vertically centre align the images (using the `\includegraphics[valign=..` key from the adjustbox package, but often better to do this "by eye" so use

```
\rotatebox{90}{\hspace{3cm}70\%}} 
\includegraphics[scale=0.155]{resfig/gt/00135.png}
```

adjusting the `\hspace` to whatever looks right next to your image.